# Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of functions on $[a,b]$ such that each $f_n$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of functions on $[a,b]$ such that each $f_n$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ and there exists $M>0$ such that $|f_n'(x)|≤M$ for all $x \in (a,b)$ and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

If $(f_n)$ converges pointwise on $[a,b]$, show that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$.

I have tried to do integration on both sides of $|f_n'(x)|≤M$, and conclude $f_n$ is Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: yes, $f_n$ is indeed lipschitz continuous. What is your background? Do you know the fundamental theorem of calculus, or the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem?

Comment: I know  the fundamental theorem of calculus. Do i have to apply it in this question?